# Get render metadata programmatically

Tags: python, scripting

I'm looking for a way to get a render's metadata when its finished using python (without having to save it).
basically i want to print out the meta data using the render_complete if that's possible
any thoughts?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that yet.  Task [T84598](https://developer.blender.org/T84598) is an open To-Do (bug) to "Add Python API for Image meta data".  The interface you need doesn't exist.